# When to use $m(\measuredangle ABC)$ vs $\angle ABC$

Tags: geometry, convention

In geometry problems, usually I see something like $\angle ABC=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ when an angle needs to be given a measure. However, sometimes I see people write that same equation as $m(\measuredangle ABC)=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$. What is the correct notation?

Comment: Whatever you agreed on? I personally have never seen the second so it might even mean something else for all I know, but as long as the reader knows what you mean it's all good. In doubt, write the definition down so the reader *definitely* knows what you mean. Math is about the ideas and concepts, not about the language or notation you write it in.

Comment: Do you say $\angle ABC$ for the angle itself, or for the measure of the angle?  Similarly, do you say $\overline{AB}$ for the line segment itself, or for the length of the line segment?  Follow the notation used by those you are communicating with.

Comment: @GEdgar I use both notations for both

Comment: FYI: Some countries $m$ is used for slope of a straight line such as $y=mx+c$ where $c=$intercept, and $m=\tan\theta$ ($\theta$ is the slope).

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Yeah, but in different contexts, symbols mean different things, such as $\pi$ as a constant and $\pi(x)$ for the prime-counting function.

Comment: The usage in the OP (which I also see in US high school) is $m(\angle ABC)$ for "the measure of angle $ABC$".  This may be because it is confusing to beginners to use one notation for two different things.

Answer (score 2):

It's not wrong to use either. The symbol ∠ is usually used for angles we don't know the size of, while ∡ is used for measured angles, for example 
|∡ABC|=70˚ or m(∡AMC)=120˚, so, I recommend using the second notation in your case as you know the angle size, but otherwise, use the other notation.

Comment: Does the absolute value also indicate the measure?

Comment: I am pretty sure it does

Comment: Are you sure it's m(∡), not m(∠)? And why are parentheses there? Is it a function? (If so, How is it defined as?)